# How to avoid unnecessary api calls and execute api call only when there is some change at the server side

Tags: android, kotlin, synchronization, android-sqlite, android-room

```
fun getNotifications(priorityNum: Int) =
        object : NetworkBoundResource<List<Notification>, Resource<List<Notification>>>(exec) {
            override fun saveCallResult(item: Resource<List<Notification>>) {
                item.data!!.forEach {
                    val id = db.notification().insert(it)
                    if (id == -1L) {
                        db.notification().update(
                            it.id,
                            it.subject,
                            it.description,
                            it.priority,
                            it.community,
                            it.createdTime
                        )
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun shouldFetch(data: List<Notification>?) = true

            override fun loadFromDb(): LiveData<List<Notification>> {
                return db.notification().getAllNotifications()
            }

            override fun createCall(): LiveData<ApiResponse<Resource<List<Notification>>>> =
                api.getNotifications(pref.userId!!, priorityNum)

        }.asLiveData()
```

I am using something like this in my repository for local database.What I want is that you can see the shouldFetch() is always true, which results in API call even if the data is not changed. So, that causes unwanted API calls.How to avoid this and call the back end only when there is  a new insertion or update at the server side

Comment: you can generate a push notification and when received then make the api call

Comment: It's not good way to use Firebase notification for sync options but you can do something like send notification to each users when something happen from your back-end like new record add or some delete operation perform. based on that you can receive silent notification and update your code. Silent notification made by setting particular type in notification.

Comment: What can be used to get this silent notification. If push notifications come we can identify right!!!...  @Madhav

Comment: you have to made some logic like in your notification message take 1 variable or filed which indicate that this is silent notification

Comment: in my case we creating 1 json string with notification type and send it in message object and upon notification type i'm updating interface.

Comment: So you too are using push notifications right

Comment: yes  but my scenario is different.

Comment: So are you not using Firebase Push notifications?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199883/discussion-between-madhav-and-abraham-mathew).